# Unable to retrieve the id property from rc-time-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timepicker

I am using rc-time-picker in Reactjs. It displays fine.
I am able to access its **`value`** property,
However, I am trying to access the **`id`** property of the rc-time-picker and unable to do so.

```
import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css';
import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker';
import moment from "moment";


<TimePicker

       onChange={ function(value, id){console.log(value, id)} }

                                          id={item.day}
                                          defaultValue={moment()}
                                          value={moment(item.start, format)}
                                          format={format}
                                          disabled={!item.isChecked}
                                          showSecond={false}
                                        />
```

Console outputs only the **value** property, while **id** property is shown as undefined.

Github Ref: https://github.com/react-component/time-picker

Any help will be highly appreciated here.

Comment: Please show full code example. Do you have multiple `<TimePicker>`s or what do you mean?

Comment: Can you try this: `onChange={(value) => this.handleTimePickerChange(value, item.day)}`

Comment: @pintu - tried that didn't work. ty for trying.

Comment: @MagnusMelwin
try now: `onChange={(value, id=item.day) => this.handleTimePickerChange(value, id)}`
I have tested the same and working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by following way:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: moment(),
  };

  handleValueChange = (value, id) => {
    console.log(value && value.format('HH:mm:ss'));
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  clear = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: undefined,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <TimePicker
        id={item.day}
        defaultValue={value}
        onChange={(value, id=item.day) => this.handleValueChange(value, id)}
    />
        <button onClick={this.clear} type="button">
          clear
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this solve the issue.

Comment: Ty Pintu Kumar. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can also use refs here, btw Thank :)